# how can I get the "ID" of selected value in Jquery Ui Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using JqueryUI autocomplete . after source method i written select method. in that ui.item.value showing the result what i selected value, but ui.item.id is not working it showing 'undefined' . how can i get seleted value ID? please find my code here http://jsfiddle.net/hari034/R8xGA/

sample code URL returns:

> 3045:MUM:MUMBAI^

Description:

> 3045 : placeID
>
> MUM  : Place Code
>
> MUMBAI : place Name.

^      : all placed coming from DB separated by "^"

Comment: The Question is too Abstract. Can you paste your code ?

Comment: my code link http://jsfiddle.net/hari034/R8xGA/

Comment: Please provide sample returned value from applicationURL (ajax)

Comment: sample code URL returns:  3045:MUM:MUMBAI^

Description:
 
3045   : placeID
MUM    : Place Code
MUMBAI : place Name.
^      : all placed coming from DB separated by "^"

Comment: try this, var item_id = ui.item.id; then use item_id for both alerts, see if that works, maybe something else is somehow changing the code?

Comment: i tried with your suggestion, but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

`ui.item.id` is `undefined` because you're not adding it to each `item` in autocomplete's source. You can accomplish this by tweaking your `succeess` function in your AJAX call:

```
success: function(data) {

    fromPlacesNamesList = new Array();
    var f = data.split("^");
    for (indx = 0; indx < f.length - 1; indx++) {
        var f1 = f[indx].split(':');
        fromPlacesNamesList[indx] = { label: f1[2], id: f1[0] };
    }
    response(fromPlacesNamesList);
    return false;
} //success
```

Additionally, you should have been calling `response` from outside of your for loop.

**Updated example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7GBTH/

Comment: thanks Andrew, is there any difference writing response out side  of for loop? before i placed inside it working fine, but auto suggestions it taking 2-5 secs time.

Comment: thanks Andrew, is there any difference writing response out side  of for loop? before i placed inside it working fine, but auto suggestions it taking 2-5 secs time to populate. i have another issue also if search place names  with 'NEL' the autosuggestions showing 'NEGLORE','NELORE'....why it showing starting NEG...? i checked in my java class response coming starting NEL..but auto complete showing NEG...NEL.....

Comment: @hari: You're building a list of suggestions to send to the widget. This means that you have to let your `for` loop run and populate that list. Calling `response` inside the loop will notify the widget of suggestions on every iteration, which I don't think is what you want. As for the problem with the suggestions, its probably something with your server-side (Java) code.

Comment: thanks Andrew after calling response out side of for loop , results are populating immediately. before what happen is, i hope for every iteration response is generated , may that is the cause mouse blinking(loop iterating internal) and final result displayed. but in IE-6 combo-box values are overlapping the auto suggestion values.

Comment: @hari: I'm not sure what you mean. Is it possible for you to reproduce this in an example?

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared some kind of resolution for your problem. There is no direct way to get information from autocomplete (or at least I don't know it). Please find working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/R8xGA/3/

Basically you need to save results ids in global array which is later on accessed in select.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: You basically need to add 3 elements

1. Before `for(indx=0;indx<f.length-1;indx++){` add array reset `ids = new Array;`
2. In for statement declare array with ids with value as a key `ids[f1[2]] = f1[0];`
3. Get the information from your array in select phase `ids[ui.item.value]`

PS. This trick will not work if you have duplicated values. It will be tough to add support for such use case.

Best,
Marek

Comment: Thanks Marek , it working fine for your logic. but it taking few seconds to displaying result.here i have one doubt can i give source as "result.jsp" . my requirement is user can enter placeName or Placecode in text Box, in both cases i have to populate place name.other please suggest me, good example.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve. Yes you can use result.jsp in there and generate content on the fly. I used static return as I didn't had it prepared. If you can host api that will be accessible via internet I can use it in this example (after some adjustments as there will be problem with cross-domain).

Comment: Another thing is that if you want to change value in the input (for example by adding ID to it) than it's no problem... but as I told you before I'm not sure what are your goals. If you could describe it a little further.

Comment: i have one web application contains home.html as home page. this page have "From Place" as text box with auto complete.in this field user can enter place Name or place code , in both scenarios , i have to populate place name. but the placeNames(data) will come from different application. these placeNammes mixed with PlaceID, PlaceName, PlaceCode,PlaceName. . my present code is working fine. but after entering the minLength 3 chares in Text box mouse is blinking upto 2-5 secs then suggetions are displaying.